# How to Implement Tile Caching for Leaflet in React?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, tiles

I'm currently working on a project using React with Leaflet for mapping functionality. I've been exploring options to optimize performance, and one area I'm interested in is caching Leaflet tiles to reduce the number of network requests and improve loading times.

I've searched through the documentation and various resources online, but I haven't found a clear, straightforward way to implement tile caching in React using Leaflet.

Comment: Let the browser do the caching for you. Do not overengineer.